# How to provide initial data for an HTML fragment having it's own controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a typical Angular application, I have been using resolves to load data required for a controller working on a template for a route.

Now I am working on an application, where we have HTML fragments inside a route. How do I provide some sort of dependency for individual fragments like I do for the whole route.

I want them to work like a mini ng-view each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-include like this:

```
<div ng-include="'myFragment.html'"></div>
```

Or if you have the fragment name in a variable (called fragment for example) on the scope:

```
<div ng-include="fragment"></div>
```

Your html fragment can then have a controller using the **ng-controller="myFragmentController"** syntax on the root element.

Comment: My question is, if the fragment has to load some data from the server before displaying anything, how do I do it ?

Comment: Why not code your fragment controller to load the data needed?